# How to identify and split a paragraph or merged text into sub parts in Word document having list of decimal, alphabet, roman, and sub points

Tags: vba, ms-word

We regularly get closed text/merged text in Word document

It will have numerical numbering (1 to 10).

For example this is the text containing 7 points. I want it to be splitted into sub parts.

**AGENDA OF THE MEETING**

1.OPENING OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS. 2.ELECTION OF THE CHAIRPERSON OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS. 3.PREPARATION OF THE ATTENDANCE LIST, ACKNOWLEDGEMENT THAT THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS HAS BEEN CONVENED APPROPRIATELY AND IS CAPABLE OF ADOPTING BINDING RESOLUTIONS. 4.ADOPTION OF THE AGENDA OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING. 5.ADOPTION OF THE RESOLUTION REGARDING THE SALE OF AN ORGANISED PART OF ENTERPRISE. 6.ADOPTION OF THE RESOLUTION AMENDING THE COMPOSITION OF THE SUPERVISORY BOARD OF THE BANK. 7.CLOSING OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS

Result:

1.OPENING OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS.

2.ELECTION OF THE CHAIRPERSON OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS.

3.PREPARATION OF THE ATTENDANCE LIST, ACKNOWLEDGEMENT THAT THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS HAS BEEN CONVENED APPROPRIATELY AND IS CAPABLE OF ADOPTING BINDING RESOLUTIONS.

4.ADOPTION OF THE AGENDA OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING.

5.ADOPTION OF THE RESOLUTION REGARDING THE SALE OF AN ORGANISED PART OF ENTERPRISE.

6.ADOPTION OF THE RESOLUTION AMENDING THE COMPOSITION OF THE SUPERVISORY BOARD OF THE BANK.

7.CLOSING OF THE EXTRAORDINARY GENERAL MEETING OF SHAREHOLDERS

Can you provide a macro to separate/split. The numbering will execute 1 , 2....103, 104 etc  Please help.

Coming to second question if the numbering is in Romans (I, II, III, IV ) and in alphabet (A, B, C, D) form how to create a macro to split those:

EXAMPLE TEXT:

**Numbering as alphabets**

A. Presentation of the  financial statements and annual  report for the 2010 financial year  with the report of the Supervisory  Board, the group financial  statements, the group annual  report, and the report pursuant to  Sections 289(4) and 315(4) of the  German Commercial Code B.  Ratification of the acts of the Board of MDs C. Ratification of the acts of the Supervisory  Board D. Appointment of  auditors for the 2011 financial  year: PricewaterhouseCoopers AG,  Frankfurt E. Elections to the  Supervisory. Board (1) Peter Maria Wagner (2) Michael Hirschi (3)  Andrea Sieber

Output:

A. Presentation of the  financial statements and annual  report for the 2010 financial year  with the report of the Supervisory  Board, the group financial  statements, the group annual  report, and the report pursuant to  Sections 289(4) and 315(4) of the  German Commercial Code

B.  Ratification of the acts of the Board of MDs

C. Ratification of the acts of the Supervisory  Board

D. Appointment of  auditors for the 2011 financial  year: PricewaterhouseCoopers AG,  Frankfurt

E. Elections to the  Supervisory. Board (1) Peter Maria Wagner (2) Michael Hirschi (3)  Andrea Sieber

**Numbering as alphabets and have sub-points with a number**

A.1 Presentation of the financial statements and annual  report for the 2010 financial year  with the report A.2 Supervisory  Board, the group financial  statements, the group annual  report A.3 the report pursuant to  Sections 289(4) and 315(4) of the  German Commercial Code B.  Ratification of the acts of the  Board of MDs C.1 Ratification  of the acts of the Supervisory  Board C.2. Appointment of auditors for the 2011 financial  year: PricewaterhouseCoopers AG,  Frankfurt C.3. Elections to the Supervisory. Board (1) Peter Maria  Wagner (2) Michael Hirschi (3)  Andrea Sieber

output:

A.1 Presentation of the financial statements and annual  report for the 2010 financial year  with the report

A.2 Supervisory  Board, the group financial  statements, the group annual  report

A.3 the report pursuant to  Sections 289(4) and 315(4) of the  German Commercial Code

B.  Ratification of the acts of the  Board of MDs

C.1 Ratification  of the acts of the Supervisory  Board

C.2. Appointment of auditors for the 2011 financial  year: PricewaterhouseCoopers AG,  Frankfurt

C.3. Elections to the Supervisory. Board (1) Peter Maria  Wagner (2) Michael Hirschi (3)  Andrea Sieber

**Numbering as alphabets [Roman numbers]**

I. Presentation of the financial statements and annual report for the 2010 financial year with the report II. Supervisory Board, the group financial statements, the group annual report III. the report pursuant to Sections 289(4) and 315(4) of the German Commercial Code IV. Ratification of the acts of the Board of MDs V. Ratification of the acts of the Supervisory Board VI. Appointment of auditors for the 2011 financial year: PricewaterhouseCoopers AG, Frankfurt VII. Elections to the Supervisory. Board (1) Peter Maria Wagner (2) Michael Hirschi VIII. Election of Andrea Sieber as a director

output:

I. Presentation of the financial statements and annual report for the 2010 financial year with the report

II. Supervisory Board, the group financial statements, the group annual report

III. the report pursuant to Sections 289(4) and 315(4) of the German Commercial Code

IV. Ratification of the acts of the Board of MDs

V. Ratification of the acts of the Supervisory Board

VI. Appointment of auditors for the 2011 financial year: PricewaterhouseCoopers AG, Frankfurt

VII. Elections to the Supervisory. Board (1) Peter Maria Wagner (2) Michael Hirschi

VIII. Election of Andrea Sieber as a director

Please help in developing macro for normal numerical, (1,2,3,4..10,103,178 so on) Roman numbering (I, II, III, IX, X, XII....XXV So on), alphabets (A, B, C....X,Y,Z) and  for spliting

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: I want to bifurcate the numbering as per the paragraph/closed text.
If numbering is stated with 1, 2, 3  ……100,101 and so on. In the same way Roman numbering I, II, III AND …. And in the same way we have alphabet numbering as A, B, C,D……X, Y, Z

Comment: Generally SO isn't going to write code for you. You might want to try using the macro recorder to get yourself started if you aren't familiar with VBA. For instance, one approach would be to write a search and replace that finds the numbers and puts a paragraph break before each one. You'd need to do some testing to see if that would be feasible for your material. Once you have a basic macro, you can post it and get help improving it or expanding it.

Comment: I record the code: Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^#."
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^&"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    

    End With

Comment: Please update your question with the new code and explain what is working and what isn't. It's very difficult to read code in the comment section, and it's equally hard to help you without more details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is the following. You have an array of delimiters. And you would like to return new paragraph and the same delimiter.

So the problem splits into parts.

- Create the delimiters. There are three types:

  - **Arabic numerals**. Here is the array: `("1.", "2.", "3.", "4.", "5.", "6.", "7.", "8.", "9.", "10.", "11.", "12.", "13.", "14.", "15.", "16.", "17.", "18.", "19.", "20.")`. If you need more numbers: http://textmechanic.com/generate-list-numbers/.
  - **Latin letters**. Here is the array: `("A.", "B.", "C.", "D.", "E.", "F.", "G.", "H.", "I.", "J.", "K.", "L.", "M.", "N.", "O.", "P.", "Q.", "R.", "S.", "T.", "U.", "V.", "W.", "X.", "Y.", "Z.")`.
  - **Roman numerals**. Here is the array: `("I.", "II.", "III.", "IV.", "V.", "VI.", "VII.", "VIII.", "IX.", "X.", "XI.", "XII.", "XIII.", "XIV.", "XV.", "XVI.", "XVII.", "XVIII.", "XIX.", "XX.")`. If you need more numbers, take this http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/roman_numerals.htm#list, copy-paste here: http://textmechanic.com/delimited-column-extractor/ and use  as delimiter, then add needed prefix and suffix http://textmechanic.com/add-prefixsuffix-into-line/.
- Replace delimiter for paragraph and delimiter. Find `delimiter` and replace for `^pdelimiter`. You need a loop.

Here is the **sample code** with all **Latin letters**:

```
Option Explicit
Sub replaceArrayForArray()
'
'to create array use prefix\suffix and replacing tool http://textmechanic.com/
'
'
findArray = Array("A.", "B.", "C.", "D.", "E.", "F.", "G.", "H.", "I.", "J.", "K.", "L.", "M.", "N.", "O.", "P.", "Q.", "R.", "S.", "T.", "U.", "V.", "W.", "X.", "Y.", "Z.")
replArray = Array("A.", "^pB.", "^pC.", "^pD.", "^pE.", "^pF.", "^pG.", "^pH.", "^pI.", "^pJ.", "^pK.", "^pL.", "^pM.", "^pN.", "^pO.", "^pP.", "^pQ.", "^pR.", "^pS.", "^pT.", "^pU.", "^pV.", "^pW.", "^pX.", "^pY.", "^pZ.")

For i = 0 To UBound(findArray)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = findArray(i)
        .Replacement.Text = replArray(i)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next i
End Sub
```

Adapt your code for **Arabic numerals**, and **Roman numerals**.